# Android WebRTC Custom Capturer

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, webrtc

I have compiled the webRTC Demo app. I see that capturing the frames is done by the `VideoCaptureAndroid.java` file that is tightly coupled with the native code.
I need to add a functionality of pushing my own frames to the webRTC library to send on the video channel.

I'm ok with writing it in C++, or with NDK or Java. But I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm in the exact same boat, wanting to send the contents of a glFrameBuffer over webRTC

Comment: you have to rebuild webrtc and jni into it.

Comment: Yes, I did find the solution. (It was a while ago) you really need to get the source code of webRTC in C++, and expose the right methods for that to Java through jni. I did it a long time ago and I don't have code with me, since I don't work for that company anymore. It took me a few days of work. So it's doable, but it was not available out of the box